# Mirror existing weight paint to other bones

Tags: weight-painting

I have seen many similar questions but haven't been able to find an answer for my specific issue

As you can see in the image, the arm on the right is properly painted, and the arm on the left has NO weights at all. I want the left arm to have the exact same weights as the right one for the corresponding bones.
[image]

I'm aware of the symmetry options, which are useful, but require me to repaint the bone. I'd like to just copy over the existing weights to the other side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite several tutos I've not found a way to make it work properly for several vertex groups at once (which seems weird for such a basic operation), also it seems buggy in some versions, but for one vertex group and for 3.3, select the vertex group you want to mirror in the *Vertex Groups* list and copy:

[image]

It will create a new vertex group, select it and mirror it:

[image]

At last, give it the right suffixe (here, "_R"):

[image]

If you want to symmetrize **when weight painting**, in 3.3, once in *Weight Paint* mode, open the *N panel > Tool > Symmetry* and activate the *Mirror Vertex Groups* and *X* options:

[image]